# How do I rewire from this old bathroom switch to new?

Tags: bathroom

I have never seen a switch like this before and although I have changed out many I can't seem to wrap my head around this particular one. Any help would be appreciated. My light in the bathroom will not turn off so I need to replace it. I'm going from this old one and hopefully to this Legrand 2 in 1 paddle switch.[image]

Comment: What seems to be the exact problem?  That switch uses push in connections(quite common), and seems to control two devices(red and black wires on top).  Maybe the light and exhaust fan.

Comment: What does this switch turn on and off?

Comment: Yes it is the bathroom light and the fan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to find which wire is hot. Most likely the black closest to the thumb in your pic. That goes to the line screw on the new switch. ( or the screw that is alone on one side.) The other 2 wires (the red and other black) go to the screws on the opposite side of the new switch.

Comment: you are welcome. Please upvote my answer.

Comment: I think I may be a tad stupid. I don't know how to upvote.. if you tell me how I will.

Comment: click the up triangle to the left of the answer

Comment: So I did it assuming the hot wire was the one closest to the thumb in the pic but only the fan works. Could the red one be the hot wire instead?

Comment: It is possible the red is hot. Can you show a pic of the new switch with the connections present.